# Arranging items in a panel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

I'm coding a small project for my high school class but I have run into a bit of an issue now that I'm working with frames. I'm trying to find the easiest and most efficient way to arrange the contents of a panel in java 7 ***(Note: this means SpringUtilities is not an option)***

For the arrangement of each item I wanted it to have the option to type in your name at the top and then have 3 buttons in the same row below the name box

and the code I have so far is

```
   private static void userInterface(){
        //Declare and assign variables
        final String[] options = {"Lvl 1", "Lvl 2", "Lvl 3"};
        int optionsAmt = options.length;
        //Create the panel used to make the user interface
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new SpringLayout());

        //Create the name box
        JTextField tf = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel l = new JLabel("Name: ");
        l.setLabelFor(tf);
        panel.add(l);
        panel.add(tf);

        //Create 3 buttons with corresponding values of String options
        for(int a = 0; a < optionsAmt; a++){
            JButton b = new JButton(options[a]);
            panel.add(new JLabel());
            panel.add(b);
        }

        //Layout the panel


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.pack();
        f.setTitle("Number Game");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Easy" is a relative term, for example, you could do something like...

[image: GridLayout]

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    public TestPane() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

        JPanel fieldPane = new JPanel();
        fieldPane.add(new JTextField(10));
        add(fieldPane);

        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
        buttonPane.add(new JButton("1"));
        buttonPane.add(new JButton("2"));
        buttonPane.add(new JButton("3"));
        add(buttonPane);

    }

}
```

or something like...

[image: GridBagLayout]

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    public TestPane() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = 3;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;

        add(new JTextField(10), gbc);

        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;

        add(new JButton("1"), gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
        add(new JButton("2"), gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
        add(new JButton("3"), gbc);

    }

}
```

Both are easy, both do the job, but which you would use would depend greatly on what you want to achieve...

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details